# Ubuntu 12.10 recognizes wireless but no internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet

Can anyone help me with this? I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed and it is even connected to my Wifi but I am unable to go to any web pages in firefox.

edit:

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:8c:41:5a:fb  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:18 

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:25004 (25.0 KB)  TX bytes:25004 (25.0 KB)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:7d:68:c1:a7:a8  
      inet addr:10.0.0.12  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::f27d:68ff:fec1:a7a8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:27761 (27.7 KB)  TX bytes:28587 (28.5 KB)

    wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:9c:03:5a:b7  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

ping -c5 8.8.8.8

```
    PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 10.0.0.12 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.12 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.12 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.12 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.12 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable

    --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
    5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
    pipe 3
```

iwconfig

```
    wlan1     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:on

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"thepenismighter"  
              Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:1D:D6:17:F4:30   
              Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off
              Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
              Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
              Tx excessive retries:17  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Can you post the result of sudo ifconfig

Comment: Also `ping -c5 8.8.8.8`

Comment: And also `iwconfig`

Comment: I edited the post with the requested information.

Comment: If you can ping and get a respond from 10.0.0.1 but not from google.com for example, then the problem is not your network card or Ubuntu but the router you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Comment: It started working for no apparent reason...

Comment: I can actually ping 10.0.0.1 and www.google.com fine, but the connection is not good within firefox or the software center. It times out a lot.